# regex to mask IBAN

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind, iban

I want to mask IBAN. I have to show only first 7 characters and last 4 characters.

Example:

Input:

```
PL61109010140000071219812874
```

Output:

```
PL61109***********2874
```

I wrote the following regex:

```
(?<=.{7})(.*)(?=.{4})
```

but js do not support lookbehind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use groups in Regex to do that instead of LookBehind

```js
var myString = "PL61109010140000071219812874";
var myRegexp = /\w{7}(.*)\w{4}/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
myString = myString.replace(match[1], '*********');
console.log(myString)
```

Comment: @Nemesis My pleasure

Answer (score 2):

`(?<=.{7}` is a lookbehind assertion, unfortunately Javascript regex doesn't  support lookbehind.

You can use `substr` and a lookahead for this in Javascript:

```js
var s = 'PL61109010140000071219812874';

var r = s.substr(0,7) + s.substr(7).replace(/.(?=.{4,}$)/g, '*');

console.log(r);
```

- `s.substr(0,7)` - Gets characters from start to 7th position
- `s.substr(7)` - Gets characters from 7th position onwards
- `.replace(/.(?=.{4,}$)/g, '*')` - Using lookahead, replaces all but last 4 characters with `*`